# Return by value, and by address

Tags: c++, pointers, return-value

```
#include <iostream>

int Value ()
{
     int x = 90;//creates a variable x
     return x;//returns the value x, into the caller
     //x is destroyed because it is out of scope
}

int * ptr ()
{
     int x = 7;//creates variable x
     return &x;//returns a pointer to x
     //x gets destroyed because it is out of scope
}
```

Inside main function

```
      int y = Value ();// y = 7

      int *py = ptr ();
      /* *py = 7, not Undefined Behaviour?? */
```

I create this code, and in debugging the program, I *py = 7 in my watch window.
Shouldn't I get an Undefined behaviour, and the program crash, since py points to an address that have garbage now (x in ptr() is out of scope)

Comment: The problem with UB is that one of the possibilities is that it *seems* to work. Try changing the order of the calls and you will most likely see `*py` change value after the call to `Value`.

Comment: I did  now it gives me 0. Thanks

Comment: This is also very compiler and OS dependent. This is what it is meant by undefined-behavior because it is implementation defined rather than being guaranteed to work the same under every circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function ptr returns a value, the address of the local variable x. While you end your function the memory model only mark this address (&x) as writeable, but the actual value in the memory will not be deleted.
So when you look at the actual values of the memory address py, you will see the value 7 but it could be changed when another function will ask for some memory.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't I get an Undefined behaviour

Yes. That is what you got.

> Shouldn't ... the program crash

No. The standard does not define that the program must crash. Instead, the behaviour is n undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It's become a `dangling pointer`. which will cause problems if used.